# Compilation error in visual C++

Tags: c, visual-c++, compiler-errors, yacc

I am using Visual studio 2010 for building C project. My project contains a number of header files,source file and parsers. It uses `lex` and `bason` files. I am getting a single error during the compilation and íé the following

```
abc.y:error C2065: 'INPUT' : undeclared identifier
```

I tried the solutions I am getting  like including

```
#define WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0501
```

in my main.c file before the inclusion of any of the header files.I am not able to get rid of this error. Could you please let me know what Can be the reasons for this error?

EDIT

The snippet of code that is showing error is:

```
     list_Cons(0, list_List((POINTER)INPUT)
```

The surprising thing is that If i alter INPUT into INPUT1, I get the  same error. It is stoic to change.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/892073. Can't tell much more without seeing code.

Comment: Where does the failing line come from? Is it in a `yacc`-generated file? In that case, you have to consult yacc's manual.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you read [this](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=149452) and [this](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/windows-programming/44021-input-undeclared-identifier.html).

`#define WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0501` wont work. You should try using `#define WIN32_WINNT 0x0501` instead.

Also, check that you are actually #including winuser.h

Answer (score 0):

A C++ compiler cannot process a *.y file.  For that you need a yacc / bison program, which does not come included with Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: I don't think VS2010 has a built-in rule about how to compile `*.y`, so the problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: I have generated the corresponding header and source files that yaac and lex files generates using the lex and bison. And I am compiling those files together.

Comment: @thetna: The posted error message still looks like it's trying to compile "abc.y" with the C++ compiler.  If you already have the yacc output, you should probably make sure those files are included in the project and remove abc.y from the project.

Comment: Actually I removed those also. I am trying it. I am getting the same error.

Comment: @aschepler Perhaps abc.c is being generated from abc.y, and the c file has #line directives in it that refer back to abc.y

Answer (score 0):

For myself I use [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/runningcmake.html) which can generate MSVC projects along with other build types. You can tell it that a .y [needs to be processed](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2007-July/015395.html) outwith the C/C++ files and it will instruct MSVC to invoke whatever external tools are necessary to preprocess the non-C/C++ parts.